# How do I move folders in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have a bunch of folders under "deleted items". How do I get them back to where

they were?

I've tried dragging. All that does is put it in the next folder. Now they're all over the place. I don't want them inside another folder. I want them by themselves but you can't do that by dragging because there's no free space to drop it in

Also the "inbox" over on the left is the 5th item down. How do I put it on top?

Comment: Welcome. Please don't ask two distinct questions in the same post. "I want them by themselves"... Do you mean you want them to be top-level folders?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Outlook (which you did not state), you may not be able to move folders up, down or between layers, you can use Favorite Folders pane to do that...

---

If your version supports moving folders:

You can drag-and-drop them inside your folder list. If you want the folder to be a top-level folder just drag it over your uppermost item, should be your email address.

Your folder list should look something like this:

- youremail@example.com ← drag the folder over this item

  - inbox
  - deleted items
  - etc...

Another possibility is to use the right-click menu. 
right-click → Move Folder → select the new parent item, in your case the uppermost item (your email address).

---

Regarding your second question, you can use the "Move up" or "Move Down" options inside the right-click menu again.